# Deserialize JSON Date to C# Object with DateTime Returning 01/01/0001

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft to translate a JSON string that presents a date

```
"[{\"Name\":\"Learning\",\"Start Date\":\"2022-03-01\",\"End Date\":\"2022-04-30\"]"
```

And I want to deserialize it to this custom object

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

By doing this

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(jsonRecords,
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" });
```

But the StartDate and EndDate objects are always coming out as 01/01/0001, while I'd want them to show in this format: dd/MM/yyyy

I also tried to use `new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" }` but that didn't work either (and I think you need to use the format in which the date is coming from json?)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `DateTime` in .NET doesn't have a format. The only value it holds is the `long` value `Ticks`. Everything else is computed when the corresponding property is accessed. The formatted value you see when you look at the `DateTime` property in the debugger is a result of converting it to a `string` using your culture. So from that perspective, it isn't possible to format a value in a `DateTime`.

Comment: That's very interesting thanks! But how do I get the actually correct date (i.e. 01/03/2022) instead of that 01/01/0001? I'm not too worried about the format of course, but it would be great to have the correct date...

Comment: Just thinking as I have not tested it, but in your JSON your "Start Date" and "End Date" is written with a space. Your properties of course are named" StartDate" and "EndDate" without a space. So the names do not match which leads the deserializer to not deserialize the values into the properties. The default value of DateTime is 01.01.0001 00:00:00. So try to remove the spaces in your JSON

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `[JsonProperty("Start Date")]` above `public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }` and similar above `public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }`:

```cs
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Start Date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("End Date")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

The problem was that json property names ('Start Date') and class property names ('StartDate') were not the same so it defaulted to 01/01/0001.

This will work without the need for `IsoDateTimeConverter`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if your properties don't match the JSON properties, that's normal.
You have spaces between "Start Date" so you need to use **JsonProperty** attribute to specify the JSON property that you want to use:

```
public class MyObject
     {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="Start Date")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "End Date")]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

You see that 01/01/0001 because it's the Date time default and your values are not mapped.